# Checking Count of Records from a Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a custom-defined cursor that is pulling from a function that returns a nested table. I'm using the `TABLE` function (`DDS_COMPILE`) in the SQL of the cursor definition to pull the data. I have built a simple check  after the pull to `FETCH` records into a Record DataType Object (also custom-defined to match) and, if no data if found using the `%NOTFOUND`, it should raise an Exception.

When I run the routine for a given set of input parameters (i.e., STORE X, for CLASS Y), the code returns 1 record. I can see the record if I run the function that queries the database by itself and the record displays only if my `FETCH` statement is commented out. If the `FETCH` is uncommented, it throws a NoData Exception. So what is wrong with my `FETCH`?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
          OPEN DataReturn FOR
           SELECT 
                     DDSRecs.OrgID
                     , DDSRecs.DistrictCode
                     , DDSRecs.DistrictName
                     , DDSRecs.StoreNumber
                     , DDSRecs.StoreName
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateLastName
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateFirstName
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateMiddleName
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateLDAP
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateUID
                     , DDSRecs.AssociateDeptName
                     , DDSRecs.DeptHeadCount
                     , DDSRecs.JobCode
                     , DDSRecs.ActSourceableStatus
                     , DDSRecs.CertTargetDate
                     , DDSRecs.CertName
                     , DDSRecs.CertExpiredOn
                     , DDSRecs.CertRevokedOn
                     , DDSRecs.CertRecertStartsOn
                     , DDSRecs.CourseNumber
                     , DDSRecs.CourseNumberName
                     , DDSRecs.CourseHours
                     , DDSRecs.RegID
                     , DDSRecs.CourseStatus
                     , DDSRecs.CourseActionStatus
                     , DDSRecs.CourseTargetDate
                     , DDSRecs.CourseCompletionDate
                     , DDSRecs.CourseDenseRank
                     , DDSRecs.DueDateStatus
                     , DDSRecs.DueDate
                     , DDSRecs.RegAction
                     , DDSRecs.DeliveryMode
                     , DDSRecs.MMUFlag
                     , DDSRecs.ErrorMessage
                FROM TABLE(HDT_CORE_MAIN.DDS_COMPILE(
                          FinalOrgID
                          , ParamReportType
                          , ParamCourseNumberCheck
                          , ParamNameKeywordCheck
                     )) DDSRecs
           ;
      LOOP
           FETCH DataReturn INTO DDS_ERR_CHECK;
           IF DataReturn%NOTFOUND THEN 
                RAISE DDS_ERR_NO_DATA;
           END IF;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE DataReturn;
```

There's much more to the procedure, of course, that's not related to this issue. Utlimately, it's the loop at the end that isn't working as intended. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

---

**UPDATE:**

I've tried a couple of suggestions and changed the `FETCH LOOP` to the following:

```
          LOOP
           x := x + 1;
           FETCH DataReturn INTO DDS_ERR_CHECK;
           IF DataReturn%FOUND THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('x = ' || x);
                EXIT;
           ELSE                    
                RAISE DDS_ERR_NO_DATA;
           END IF;
          END LOOP;
```

This sees the 1 record (as it does not throw the Exception), but the 1 record is not displayed in the Output Variables. Note that the X did increment to 1 as intended.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. It looks like your code is doing just what it should be doing. You do not have anything inside your loop to do any processing, so it is starting, getting the first row, then looping immediately and trying to fetch a second row, which does not exist. That is where it is hitting the NOTFOUND and raising the exception. Try adding an incrementing variable in there and writing its value out using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count = ' || countVar);

Comment: Your code snippet does not include any "displaying output variables"? How/when is that done?

Comment: The stored procedure is used by a Crystal Reports engine to pull and display the records, so I haven't built code to display it on-screen at runtime on purpose. So far, the code had appeared to be working correctly, i.e., it does return records to the Crystal Report engine and they do display within the Crystal Report. I just noticed this issue with the 1 record, so it's possible the code wasn't sending everything back to the Crystal Reports as intended all along and I was just able to notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no exit statement to terminate your loop - it will keep on fetching until %notfound no matter how many rows in your table function.

Comment: Well, wouldn't that mean it would always return the No_Data Exception? It doesn't though. It will return records most of the time (although there maybe 1 missing).

Comment: I dont see how that is possible - unless your snippet leaves out some code between LOOP and END LOOP?

Comment: I agree...it is strange now that you bring up that issue. There's no code missing from the original.